# JSF lifecycle - Execute managed bean method after request complete

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, lifecycle

Using JSF 2.0 and Spring, I use an `@RequestScope` managed bean. This bean stores information about the logged-in user. It loads the user from the DB in a `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String username = login.getUsername();
    user = userDao.load(username);
}
```

The logged-in user can then trigger on action on the page that updates the user in database (using another managed bean).

However, the `@RequestScope` bean is constructed at the beginning of the request, which is *before* the call to the updating action. As a result, when the page is redisplayed, the `User` variable still has its old values.

My question is: do I have a way to run my loading method not at the beginning of the request, but *after* the request has been sent? Or am I dealing with this in the wrong way?

Thanks for your insight,
Sébastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The logged-in user can then trigger on action on the page that updates the user in database (**using another managed bean**).

The *same* managed bean should have been updated at that point. If you can't reuse the same managed bean for some reason, then you should manually do it by accessing it in the action method and calling the setters yourself.

---

**Update**: based on the comments, here's how the beans should be declared and injected and used in your particular requirement:

```
@ManagedBean(name="#{login}")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginManager {

    private String username;

    // ...
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean(name="#{user}")
@RequestScoped
public class UserManager {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{login}")
    private LoginManager login;
    private User current;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        current = userDAO.find(login.getUsername());
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean(name="#{profile}")
@RequestScoped
public class ProfileManager {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{user}")
    private UserManager user;

    public void save() {
        userDAO.save(user.getCurrent());
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.current.firstname}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{user.current.lastname}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{user.current.birthdate}" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{profile.save}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: In fact what seems to occur is that the Request bean is created, then the other managed bean is called and _another_ Request bean is injected. I then modify and set the new value of my User, but it won't have any effect on my initial request object. Is there a way to pass the initial request object to my other manager bean, or to retrieve it?

Comment: First this: what exactly is the reason that you put the logged-in user in a request scoped bean? Why would you need to keep this bean alive in subsequent requests? I imagined that the `login` as in your code example is actually session scoped bean and this way you ensure that the `User` contains fresh data on every request. If this is not the case, then `User` definitely needs to be a session scoped bean.

Comment: Indeed. I store the username in a session-scoped bean, and have attached the `user` to the request to make sure the data is refreshed regularly. My issue here seems to be that in my other managed bean, the `user` I retrieve (e.g. from the DB) and modify will not be propagated to the request-scoped bean (which has already been constructed when the request was fired, _before_ the call to the other managed bean that does some logic on it)

Comment: Just save changes in DB? Edit: if you have 2 request scoped beans of the same class in the same class, then there's definitely something wrong. Aren't you manually instantiating those beans instead of letting JSF do the job? In any way, you need to inject the request scoped bean holding the `User` property (as shown in your question) in the bean which is doing the update job.

Comment: The other managed bean retrieves the User from the DB, then does some changes. However I have realized that I have said some confusing things: the request-scoped bean had no reference to my other bean, it was the opposite around. In a more logical way, the request-scoped bean should reference the other one, set the User (which I guess is the setter you mentioned) then call the other managed bean method. I'll change the associations around and keep you updated. Edit: seems like ths injection of the User property is exactly the issue I had not understood.

Comment: You might be somewhere doing a `User user = new User()` while you shouldn't do that. You should use the one which is managed by JSF. I updated the answer to inculude an example of how it should work. Edit: re the previous comment, when I said "in the same class" I meant do say "in the same request".

Comment: Your code sample helped my understand my mistake (I mixed the injections, and the RequestScored was injected in the SessionScoped). Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: You're welcome. Are you using spring to manage injections? JSF by itself disallows to inject a request scoped bean in a session scoped one by `@ManagedProperty`. It would have thrown an exception during creation of the session scoped bean with a message like "scope too broad" (because it wouldn't know which request scoped one it should inject, there can namely be more than one request within a session).